# Prove that $\log(z_1z_2) = \log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$ for $z_1$, $z_2$ in the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, solution-verification

What is $\log(z_1z_2)−\log(z_1)−\log(z_2)$ for $z_1$, $z_2$ in the second quadrant?

For the first part of the question $\log(z_1z_2) = \log(z1)+\log(z_2)$, I think I solved it correctly.

By using principle branch, $\log z = \ln z + i\text{Arg}z , (-pi ,pi)$.

$\log(z_1z_2)= \log (z_1z_2) + i( \theta_1 + \theta _2)  \dots = \log z_1 + \log z_2 $

Comment: If both $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in the second quadrant then $\log (z_1 z_2) = \log z_1 + \log z_2 - \pi$

Comment: Are you choosing the principal branch of the complex logarithm for all three logarithm terms?

Comment: @chaitanya That should be $2\pi$, not $\pi$.

Comment: @markviola  well z1 and z2 must be equal in part 1 since they're in the right half plane, im not sure if i got the range of the right half plane  correct. I think the range is from [-/2,   /2) then the principle branch would be (- ,  ) so basically Z1= Z2

Comment: @TaneliousWalton How are you concluding that $z_1=z_2$.  They are not assumed to be equal.  All we know if that $\pi<\arg(z_1)<\pi/2$ and $\pi<\arg(z_2)<\pi/2$.

Comment: @MarkViola  Its basically like a proof the way i see it and we are using  the principle branch so like this is my whole answer i came up with log(12)=log(12)+(1+2)= log(z1) + log(z2) + 1+ 2 = log[(z1) + 1] +log[(z2 + 2] = log1+log2  , that part 1 for the  right half  plane question , part 2 is the 2nd quadrant question

Comment: @TaneliousWalton That proof is flawed.  See my posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we define the complex logarithm on the principal branch, then

$$\log(z)=\text{Log}(|z|)+i\text{Arg}(z)$$

with $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$ and $\text{Log}(x)$ denotes the logarithm from real analysis.

---

If $\pi/2<\text{Arg}(z_1)<\pi$ and $\pi/2<\text{Arg}(z_2)<\pi$, then clearly $\pi<\text{Arg}(z_1)+\text{Arg}(z_2)<2\pi$.

But the principal angle associated with $z_1z_2$ is such that $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z_1z_2)<0$ and we find that $\text{Arg}(z_1)+\text{Arg}(z_2)=\text{Arg}(z_1z_2)+2\pi$.

We conclude, therefore, that

$$\begin{align}
\log(z_1z_2)&=\text{Log}(|z_1z_2|)+i\text{Arg}(z_1z_2)\\\\
&=\text{Log}(|z_1|)+\text{Log}(|z_2|)+\text{Arg}(z_1)+\text{Arg}(z_2)-2\pi\\\\
&=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)-2\pi
\end{align}$$

And we are done.